# Subexpression in ed for multiple substitutions

Tags: regular-expression, ed

Let's say I have a piece of text that says:

```
John went with Sally to the market where they bought fresh bread. There they met with Jim and dined together.
```

Let's say that I wanted to write a regex to surround the names John, Sally and Jim with plus signs, as in,

```
+John+ went with +Sally+ to the market where they bought fresh bread. There they met with +Jim+ and dined together.
```

I created the following regex which successfully changes the 1st name to +John+:

```
g/\(.*\)\(\<John\>\)\(.*\)/s//\1+\2+\3/gp
```

I would like to create one that replaces all three names at once, without the need to re-run the command.

I tried a simple multiple substitution, such as:

```
g/John/s//+&+/\
s/Sally/+&+/\
s/Jim/+&+/p
```

But this only changed the first instance of each name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your editing command is *almost* correct.

```
g/./ s/John/+&+/g\
s/Sally/+&+/g\
s/Jim/+&+/gp
```

There are two main changes here:

1. The regular expression used with the `g` command needs to be something that matches all lines that we may want to apply the command list to.  You used `John`, which means `Sally` won't be changed to `+Sally+` unless there's a `John` on the same line.

   I'm using `.` here to select all non-empty lines, but you could also use e.g. `^` or `$` to select *all* lines.  It may have made more sense to use `...` so that we select lines that are long enough to contain the string `Jim`, the shortest of the three names.
2. I'm using the `g` flag with *each* of the three `s///` commands to do the substitution for each non-overlapping match on each line.  I'm using `gp` with the last substitution, but only because you did so yourself, to see the effect of the commands.

Use `\<John\>` in place of `John` if you need to differentiate it from `Johnny` and similar strings, if the basic regular expressions (BREs) of your system's C library supports it (this also goes for using thing like `\|` (alterations) in BREs, which is non-standard, but that would allow you to write `g/./ s/John\|Sally\|Jim/+&+/gp` on a GNU system).

Comment: The dot in the first line is unnecessary. A global search in ed (g) by default looks at  every line for the string in question. This is a cleaner solution:

g/John/s//+&+/g\

s/Sally/+&+/g\

s/Jim/+&+/gp

Bear in mind too that this does not employ a sub-expression, which I had hoped to use.

Comment: @devcom Do you not want to change `Sally` and `Jim` if there is no `John`?  Note that the last two substitutions would not be carried out unless `John` matches on the line.

Comment: Yes I do want to change those names if there is no John.

Comment: How would you then explain the dot?

Comment: @devcom The regular expression, `re`, used in `g/re/` determines what lines the subsequent command(s) are applied to.  Using a dot means "apply the following command(s) to any line containing at least one character".

Comment: I have learned something new! Thank you so much @Kusalananda

Comment: At least with GNU ed, you can do `g/\<(John\|Sally\|Jim\>/s//+&+/gp` using BRE alternation within the regex

Comment: @steeldriver I've tried a few variations of this with GNU `ed` on OpenBSD without success, so I think it's safe to say that it's the underlying regular expression implementation in the system's C library that makes the difference, not the `ed` implementation.

Comment: @steeldriver there is a redundant parenthesis in your example. Otherwise, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps an even more elegant solution is %s/\<John\|Sally\|Jim\>/+&+/gp

Comment: (1) Yes, that’s more elegant. Unfortunately it doesn’t work, because `ed` doesn’t recognize `\|`. (2) Note that ``g/John/ s//+&+/g\`` … is an error in any case. A null search string (as in `s//something/`) refers to the most recently ***processed*** regex, not the most recently *seen* one. So, on line 1, `s//+&+/g` searches for “John”, but on all subsequent lines it searches for “Jim”, because that’s the most recently processed regex.

Comment: @steeldriver: I just noticed [your most recent comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662642/subexpression-in-ed-for-multiple-substitutions#comment1246453_662661).  (1) I believe that you’re mistaken; I don’t see any reference `\|` in [this documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Regular-expressions).  (2) I can’t get it to work (in GNU Ed 1.10), even after fixing your typo of having a `(` without a matching `)`.

Comment: @Scott This does not depend on `ed`, it depends on your system's C library.  You may use `\|` to do alternations on GNU systems, but not with GNU `ed` on some others systems (like OpenBSD, which I'm using, for example).

Comment: @Scott yes indeed the parenthesis was a typo - it should be omitted altogether since the `&` replacement string doesn't need an explicit capture group (which should have been `\( ... \)` in BRE anyhow: `(` and `)` are literals). Nevertheless I'm happy to concede that @Kusalananda has posted the *correct*, *portable* solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
1,$g/./s/John/+&+/g;s/Sally/+&+/g;s/Jim/+&+/g
```

In your first `s`, you had the `g` suffix. If you put that in the second like this, then each substitute will do all the occurrences instead of just the first.

Comment: Tim, this does not work for me.

Comment: The `g` command's default address range is `1,$`, so there's no need to explicitly use that. Commands can't be delimited by `;` in `ed`.